# Windows installer problem

Tags: .net, deployment, installation

Hi I've deveoped a windows setup applicaiton using c#. When I try to install it in one of my friend's system it is asking about windows installer is not installed and .net framework also not installed messages.

How can I install those two things before I install my application. I want to integrate those values into my setup application. How is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your application is developed in .net runtime.So the target machine, on which you are trying to install your application, must have the basic required runtime installed. You can check if .net framework is installed or not from your installer class and accordingly you can prompt user to install prerequisites. Or else you can start installation from your installer by calling prerequisites executable.